# Check if accordion is open in semantic ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, semantic-ui

I´m letting my accordion collapse if a user clicks on the body of my site, but even if it´s already closed, it pops up and closes again.

Now I want to check if my accordion content is already open and only then collapse it. The documentation says nothing about such a function.

Is there any workarround for checking if an accordion is already closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it now by setting a flag inside my accordion on close and open, which I check later on

```
$('#collapse-area').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.ui.accordion').attr('open'))
        $('.ui.accordion').accordion('close', 0);
});
$('.ui.accordion').accordion({onClose: function () {
    $('.ui.accordion').attr('open', false);
}, onOpen: function () {
    $('.ui.accordion').attr('open', true);
}, collapsible: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set collapsible to true in order to can collapse accordion later:

```
$j("#AccordionDivName").accordion( "option", "collapsible", true );
```

Comment: I can collapse it, but even if it´s already collapsed, it re-inflates and collapses again